# Is there a way to identify geographies that overlap areas, not just borders?

Tags: r, r-sf, r-sp

I'm trying to take a dataset of ZIP codes and limit it to just ZIP codes within Chicago. However, any way I try to do this merge captures either far too many or too few ZIP codes. Here's a reproducible example:

```
## Load packages
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

## Load shapefiles
ZIPs <- tigris::zctas(cb = TRUE) 
ZIPs <- sf::st_as_sf(ZIPs)

places <- tigris::places(state = "17", cb = T)
chicago <- places[places$NAME == "Chicago",]
chicago <- sf::st_as_sf(chicago)

## Filter ZIPs to those within Chicago using st_intersects
overlap <- st_filter(ZIPs, chicago, .predicate = st_intersects) #Using st_intersects captures too many ZIPs

## Visualize ZIPs vs Chicago
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = overlap, color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = chicago, color = NA, fill = "blue", alpha = .25)
```

[image: first attempt - captures too many ZIP codes]

```
## Try again using st_within
overlap <- st_filter(ZIPs, chicago, .predicate = st_within) #Using st_within captures too few ZIPs

## Visualize ZIPs vs Chicago
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = overlap, color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = chicago, color = NA, fill = "blue", alpha = .25)
```

[image: second attempt - captures too few]

I've also tried to use `sp::over` for this task but run into the same problem. There are clearly some ZIPs that are mostly outside of Chicago, but legitimately have some overlap (e.g. the three ZIPs on the top left of the first map). However there are others that only intersect along a border (e.g. top right), and even one that doesn't appear to intersect at all (bottom right). I want to *exclude* from this map any ZIPs that only intersect by border. Any advice?

Comment: In addition to the comments below, I found this thread is also helpful (and shows how to solve this with a custom predicate function, if that's preferable) https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1125

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I proposed a function that can filter the `ZIPs` based on the ratio of intersected area and the original area compared to a threshold. Below is an example how to use this function. It seems like `threshold = 0.3` works pretty well, but you can set any threshold based on your needs.

```
## Load packages
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# A function that can filter ZIPs based on the ratio of intersected area to original area
# The default of the threshold is set to be 0.3
# If the ratio is larger than or equal to 0.3, that ZIPs would be kept
intersection_area <- function(x, y, threshold = 0.3){
  z <- st_intersection(x, y)
  z2 <- z %>% 
    mutate(Area_Inter = as.numeric(st_area(.))) %>%
    select(ZCTA5CE10, Area_Inter) %>%
    st_set_geometry(NULL)
  x2 <- x %>%
    st_filter(y, .predicate = st_intersects)  %>%
    mutate(Area = as.numeric(st_area(.))) %>%
    select(ZCTA5CE10, Area) %>%
    left_join(z2, by = "ZCTA5CE10") %>%
    mutate(Area_Ratio = Area_Inter/Area) %>%
    filter(Area_Ratio >= threshold)
  return(x2)
}

overlap <- intersection_area(ZIPs, chicago)

## Visualize ZIPs vs Chicago
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = overlap, color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = chicago, color = NA, fill = "blue", alpha = .25)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Someone more knowledgeable than I am can give you a better answer, I hope, to better understand what's going on. For now, I can improve a little bit by excluding ZCTAs where `st_touches` returns TRUE. It appears that we still get some undesirable ZCTAs. You can also assess the intersection area of each ZCTA with Chicago to see what the area is (to understand why these are being returned) -- in some cases we are talking about a very amount of overlap.

```
overlap <- st_filter(ZIPs, chicago, .predicate = st_intersects)
overlap_extra <- st_filter(overlap, chicago, .predicate = st_touches)
nrow(overlap_extra) # Will remove 8 ZCTAs that are touching only
overlap_removed <- 
  overlap[-which(overlap$ZCTA5CE10 %in% overlap_extra$ZCTA5CE10), ]

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = overlap, color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = overlap_removed, color = "red", fill = "red", alpha = 0.2,
          size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = chicago, color = NA, fill = "blue", alpha = .25)


area_intersections <- rep(NA, nrow(overlap_removed))
# Probably not the most efficient way of doing this -- 
for (i in seq(nrow(overlap_removed))) {
  area_intersections[i] <- 
    st_area(
      st_intersection(
        st_geometry(overlap_removed[i, ]), st_geometry(chicago)))
}
summary(area_intersections)
length(which(area_intersections < 1)) # 1 has less than 1m^2 overlap
length(which(area_intersections < 1000)) # 3 have less than 1km^2 overlap

# Small improvement -- if you really want to remove more ZCTAs
overlap_removed2 <- overlap_removed[-which(area_intersections < 1000), ]

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = overlap_removed, color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = overlap_removed2, color = "red", fill = "red", alpha = 0.2,
          size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = chicago, color = NA, fill = "blue", alpha = .25)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option I've figured out, using a custom predicate function in `st_filter`

```
st_overlaps_with_threshold = function(x, y, threshold) {
  int = st_intersects(x, y)
  lapply(seq_along(int), function(ix)
    if (length(int[[ix]]))
        int[[ix]][which(as.numeric(suppressMessages(st_area(st_intersection(x[ix,], y[int[[ix]],])) / st_area(x[ix,]))) > threshold)]
    else
      integer(0)
  )
}

overlap <- st_filter(ZIPs, chicago, .predicate = st_overlaps_with_threshold, threshold = .05)
```